# Excel 2007 table gets data from Access 2007 Table or Query

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2007

I have a table in an Excel file which has a connection to an Access Query.  When I first create the table in Excel, the data comes in with exactly the same order as how I set up the Access query.  When I change something in the Access query, for example if I change the name of a field but don't change the data that comes in, in Access that column stays in the same place.  But, in Excel, when I refresh the table, that column now comes at the end.  I need the columns to be in a certain order and I put them in the correct order in Access but they're not coming in the same order in Excel.  And, I need to be able to change the fields in Access from time to time without having to do a ton of work to get the columns back in the correct order in Excel.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you not build a query/view with a specified field order?  It seems that's the source of your trouble.  Something like `SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM table` rather than `SELECT * FROM table`?

Comment: It seems to be that you are hard coding the colums into your excel program.  Try using a VLOOKUP for the table column name instead of hard coding the column location

Comment: @Excellll Maybe... maybe I could just change the query in Access to a make table query (instead of a select) and connect to that.

Comment: @Excellll Part of the problem is I have around 150 fields, so it's sort of a pain... and I've already built a query in a specified order in Access.  Why do I need to do it twice?  I checked the SQL View in Access and the SQL there brings in the fields in the order I want, and the Design view shows them in that same order.  But, when I import to Excel, if I have made changes, it does not come in that order.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there's a solution for this. Excel is not smart enough to know that you changed something on the Access side. There's a fundamental fault in your design if you need to keep changing column names.

Comment: Well, I'm rehauling the system now so I had to change a few names to get things to work properly.  In the future, it would be more like adding a new column, which would actually entail changing a column named Blank (or something like that) to something else.  This wouldn't happen often but it might every few weeks.